# Finding Modulus of multiplication of two very large number with a very large number

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

In a programming exercise, I need to find out the modulus of a very large number like 2 raise to power 500000(maximum number in input), with 1000000007 as a part of other computation.

As I may have to find out many times, one way is I create an array of 5,00,000. but it will is 
blocking a huge amount of memory, so I want to know is there any better way to do this ?

Answer (score 5):

This is an excellent time to use the [repeated squaring algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).  You can compute x<sup>y</sup> (mod `modulus`) as follows:

```
int repeatedSquaring(int x, int y, int modulus) {
    if (y == 0) return 1;
    int val = repeatedSquaring(x, y / 2);
    val = (val * val) % modulus;

    if (y % 2 == 1) {
        val = (val * x) % modulus;
    }

    return val;
}
```

This algorithm requires only O(log y) multiplications and moduli to compute.  Moreover, each intermediary value is at most `modulus`<sup>2</sup>, so if your modulus is not too large you can just use plain `int`s to do the computation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You can also reduce the size of the exponent (to no more than the size of the modulus) using Euler's theorem.

Comment: `int` is not guaranteed to be able to hold `1000000007` because it's only guaranteed to have 16 bits in it. 32 are guaranteed in `long`.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze- You're not even guaranteed that.  The spec leaves the sizes of int and long unspecified, as long as sizeof(int) ≤ sizeof(long).

Comment: @templatetypedef C specifies that minimum range of `int` as -32767 to 32767  -  at least 16 bits to implement.  A similar minimum range exist for `long` requiring at least 32 bits.

Comment: @chux Are you sure about that? Can you give a citation? I was always under the impression that all of this was implementation-defined.

Comment: @templatetypedef C specs have had something like this for decades: the _minimum_ range: :  "— minimum value for an object of type int INT_MIN -32767 // −(215 − 1)" and "maximum value for an object of type int INT_MAX +32767 // 215 − 1" C11dr §5.2.4.2.1 1.  also " minimum value for an object of type long int LONG_MIN -2147483647 // −(231 − 1) ..."   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-c-or-c-standard-documents

Comment: @chux Wow, I didn't know that! I always assumed everything was implementation-specific.

Comment: @templatetypedef Not _everything_ is implementation-specific.  Note: In 2015,  `int` as 16-bit is found amongst embedded processors,  64-bit `int` can be found in some graphics processors.  `long` is at _least_ as wide as `int`, often 2x.  Suggest reading the first part of the latest C spec.

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like this?:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long PowMod(unsigned long p)
{
  unsigned long prod;

  if (p == 0)
    return 1;
  if (p == 1)
    return 2;

  prod = PowMod(p / 2);
  prod = (unsigned long long)prod * prod % 1000000007ULL;
  if (p % 2 != 0)
  {
    prod = prod * 2 % 1000000007ULL;
  }

  return prod;
}

int main(void)
{
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(3));
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(4));
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(30));
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(31));
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(32));
  printf("%lu\n", PowMod(33));
  return 0;
}
```

Output ([ideone](http://ideone.com/gjMsbP)):

```
8
16
73741817
147483634
294967268
589934536
```